# how to build app from existing objective C app (flutter)?

Tags: objective-c, flutter

As title, how to build app from existing objective C app?

In my situation, I have a existing objective C app, and I also want to use flutter to build my app more agile.

And I find and follow the Flutter adding an iOS implementation using Objective-C instruction :
https://flutter.io/platform-channels/

**But I don't know how can I build the app in Terminal/ VS Code?**

Comment: I Think it will be far more better to rebuild the entire application using flutter than trying to do it this way. You will save yourself the stress.

Answer (score 2):

Platform Channels are used for writing native codes whether in iOS or Android, for example if you have to implement a payment gateway and its SDK is not provided in Dart language but only in native language, you can directly implement the code natively and call that piece of code from flutter using a platform channel.

Platform Channel doesnt mean that you can use your previous Objective C code and continue building your application further in Flutter.

As far as I know there's no such way where you can just continue further development in flutter from your native Objective C code. and even if there was a way, it was going to be a lot more complicated.